# Can eigenvectors of a $GL(3,\mathbb R)$ matrix form a basis for $\mathbb C^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Dimension of $\mathbb C^3$  is $6$. A $GL(3, \mathbb R)$ matrix has at most $3$ distinct eigenvectors, right? So, this is impossible?

Comment: $\Bbb C^3$ has dimension $3$ as a $\Bbb C$-vector space. In linear algebra, one typically cals "dimension of $k^n$" its dimension as a $k$-vector space, if not stated otherwise.

Comment: A 3x3 real matrix, whether invertible or not, can have infinitely many $distinct$ eigenvectors. It can have at most 3 $linearly \quad independent$ eigenvectors.

Comment: @P.Lawrence Thanks. You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're considering $\Bbb{C}^3$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$, then you're right, three vectors cannot form a basis for $\Bbb{C}^3$.

If however you consider $\Bbb{C}^3$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{C}$, then yes, it is entirely possible (think for example the identity matrix).